# How to use different background colors in mixed blend mode multiply to achieve knockout text effect successfully

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gsap

I have a quick question for a small project I am building. The knockout text effect created in the code pen above uses mixed blend mode: multiply to achieve the desired knockout effect. For this to work, the parent div (.text) needs to have a background color of black and the actual text needs to have a color of white to create the knockout effect. I am looking to implement a yellow background color but mixed blend mode multiply requires black and white to work; are there any solution to achieve my goal of having a yellow background color? All help will be greatly appreciated! Here's my codepen and the code below: https://codepen.io/justjoinednow/pen/eYMjLxP

```js
var scale = (window.innerWidth / 175) + 2.5; // window / character width + scale padding
console.log(scale);

var distanceFromViewportCenterToCharCenter = 350;
var offsetAfterScaling = distanceFromViewportCenterToCharCenter * scale;
var endScale = 0.2;


gsap.fromTo(
  ".title", 
   {
     opacity: 0, transform: `translate(${offsetAfterScaling}px, 0) scale(${scale})`,
   },
   {
     opacity: 1, transform: `translate(0, 0) scale(${endScale})` , duration: 5
   }
 );
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%
}

.text {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}


.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1000px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="title">CCCCCC</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to do this without  mix-blend-mode and instead using `color:transparent` and `backdrop-filter:opactiy(0%);` but using backdrop filter is so frustrating that i have been trying for the last half hour and still haven't managed to.

Comment: yeah i tried using that approach but it wasnt working unfortunately